# PHP for Python programmers?

Tags: php, python

I'm a 5 years Python programmer, but shortly I'll be also working with PHP. Could you recommend me some readings to getting in touch with this language having in mind my Python skills?

Comment: That is not funny to joke about, Daniel.

Comment: I would read the recommendation by Daniel Dipaolo (@Dan Grossman, it's only funny because `butt_of_joke in ('PHP', 'Perl')`). If that doesn't dissuade you, I would check out the Kohana source code. It's been a while since I got over my need to inflict suffering on myself so I'm not familiar with the 3.x line but the 2.x line is choice and a good demonstration of the fact that a great programmer can write acceptable code in even the most horrible of languages.

Comment: @Dan Grossman - I don't mean to make light of it, there's a reason I knew the book existed (and it's not because I just picked the right search terms).  So I am sensitive to it, no disrespect intended.

Answer (score 4):

[This table](http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting) has a list of many cognate expressions in php, python, ruby and perl.

Answer (score 1):

[Ask HN: PHP for Python Programmers](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1682636)

Comment: Some links to specific comments in that thread would be useful.  A quick skim reveals nothing of value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with MVC start learning from Zend Framework I think it will be easier for you to understand php, right php developing this way with a right leg start.

Object oriented business logics are same in any language. 
I really want to get into python so we can exchange knowledge ;)

Comment: Pick up the Django web framework... a great many people have started there and seen the Python light...

Comment: actually I'm two days after a quickstart on turbogears , I will give Django a try , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the best resource IMHO is still php.net  there are a ton of decent books out there, but I still prefer to rely on php.net for the latest and greatest.

Comment: I have to disagree (but politely, not downvote worthy :-). The amount of incorrect statements, poor design practices and "comments taken for defacto documentation" on PHP.NET makes it a horrid resource for anything but looking up just the API signatures, IMOHO.